# How to set several Apache Spark executors per node in YARN?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I wonder how to set several Apache Spark executors per node in YARN. Do I need specify it somehow in yarn-site.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When spark runs it behaves like any other YARN application so it asks Yarn for resources so for starters you need to set up Yarn so that it would be able to accommodate your executors ([Hortonworks has some nice guidelines here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html)).

Then you can set desired number of executors and their memory when you submit a job as in the example that appears in [Spark's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/running-on-yarn.html)

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --master yarn-cluster \
    --num-executors 3 \
    --driver-memory 4g \
    --executor-memory 2g \
    --executor-cores 1 \
    lib/spark-examples*.jar \
```

Comment: sorry, did this answer how many executors per node? Please give example in terms of these configuration parameter, how many executors you would end up per node.

Comment: this setup would request 1 driver with 4gb of ram and a total of 3 executors with 2g an 1 core each. The actual number of executors would depend on YARN's ability to fulfil these request